# How can I impersonate a different user while opening a virtual directory?

Tags: asp.net, impersonation, virtual-directory

We have an ASP.NET (3.5) application which uses Forms Authentication to authenticate accounts.  On the logon form, I also get a windows login token using LogonUser, which I use to impersonate the logged on user for browsing private directories (the files are displayed in a GridView, and the user is impersonated just before the data is bound.)  I just learned that we also need to impersonate the user in a virtual directory.  Is there a way for me to impersonate just before the virtual directory is loaded, or across the entire application without switching to Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just performing a single task (like accessing a network resource) I like to use an existing AD account I create just for such purposes and call it in-code.

I like to abstract out the example found here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158, into a helper class. This will allow to do something like this...

```
helperImpersonate hI = new helperImpersonate();

if (hI.impersonateValidUser("ADUSERNAME", "DOMAIN", "PASSWORD"))
{

   //DO STUFF HERE...  

    hI.undoImpersonation(); //undo the impersoination
}//end if impersonate is true...
```

Comment: That's what I do currently, but I'm not sure where we can do the impersonation in our code when you browse a virtual directory, or if the entire thing is handled by IIS.

Comment: Why are you not unable to access the Virtual Directory using your pre-chosen AD Account when you created the Virtual Directory? Or change the settings under the Directory Security after its been created?